# Partial derivative of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vectors

I'm trying to show: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial} {\partial t}( \nabla(\phi))= \nabla\frac{\partial \phi} {\partial t} $

Am I allowed to write:

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial} {\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial\phi} {\partial x}\\\ 
\frac{\partial\phi} {\partial y}\\\ 
\frac{\partial\phi} {\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}=\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2\phi} {\partial t\partial x}\\\ 
\frac{\partial^2\phi} {\partial t\partial y}\\\ 
\frac{\partial^2\phi} {\partial t\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What have you tread so far? :)

Comment: I don't think I have come across partial differentiation of a vector before, so i'm a bit stuck, however if the above step is correct I can show the identity is correct

Comment: @lemony9201 $\nabla \phi = \mbox{grad}\, \phi(x,t)$ is the vector function the OP means.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is correct.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla \phi 
= \partial_t \sum_i e_i \partial_i \phi
=^{(*)} \sum_i e_i \partial_t \partial_i \phi
$$
writing $\partial_t = \partial / \partial t$, 
$\partial_i = \partial / \partial x_i$, 
for some basis vectors $e_i$.

Your second equation corresponds to $(*)$.

(spoiler start)

> It continues with $$\sum_i e_i \partial_t \partial_i \phi = \sum_i e_i \partial_i \partial_t \phi = \nabla\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi$$
>
>  if $[\partial_t, \partial_i] = \partial_t \partial_i - \partial_i \partial_t=0$ for $\phi$.
>
>  And this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem) is useful.

(spoiler end)

Comment: So what I wrote above is correct?